# How do I center an h1 in the body

Tags: css, html-heading

I tried centering my h1 in the body tag like this:

```
h1 {margin:0 auto}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qPDwY/

But it doesn't center. How do I fix it?

Comment: Use `text-align:center`... http://jsfiddle.net/9bSnT/ .. The `h1` is a block level element with a width of 100%.. `margin:0 auto` won't work in this instance.

Comment: `text-align: center`? `h1` is by default 100% width.

Comment: Margin: 0 auto; Works in a fixed or 100% width. You can also use text-align: center; but that will only work again as long as your width on your site is set to 100% or fixed and centered itself. The other thing you should be careful of is using text-align: center; will center all Unless you specifically point to a particular nested h1 as here .yourclass h1 {text-align: center}

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In this case:

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qPDwY/1/)**

The margin:auto rule is used when you set a width on the element, which you haven't done.

Answer (score 6):

You can center it by setting the width.

```css
h1 {
    width:500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
     <h1>My Title</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

`text-align: center` is best choice but if you still want to center it using `margin: 0 auto` you have assign some width to `H1` (a block) element.

> You can center a block-level element by giving it margin-left and
> margin-right of auto (and **it has a set width, otherwise it would be
> full width and wouldn’t need centering**). That’s often done with
> shorthand like this:
>
> ```
> .center-me {
>   margin: 0 auto;
> }
> ```
>
> **Source:**
> https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#horizontal-block

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try this:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display; block;
}
```

Comment: By default the h1 is a block level element and without a width the margin:0 auto does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

-div style="margin:0 auto; text-align:left; width:80px;"-
   sample

change the width to change the position

Answer (score 0):

What *j09691* said does work, but not all the time.

This is why I use:

```css
/* Put this inside element/class. */
transform: translateX(400px);
```

If it doesn't fit in the center of the screen for you, just adjust it.
Of course, you could use some css and/or js magic to automatically adjust it.